# Retag request: torrent -> bittorrent

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

- 15 questions [tagged 'torrent' on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/torrent)
- 48 questions [tagged 'bittorrent' on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent)

(Only 'bittorrent' is used on SO and SF.)

Answer (score 2):

The **[torrents]** tag was phased/merged a while back.

It now no longer shows any questions tagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was originally posted (TYVM Community User), 7 questions popped up with `[torrent]` on SO. I manually retagged them all to `[bittorrent]`.

Comment: it happens.  since SO/SF don't use the same tags SU does, migrated questions recreate the old non-preferred tags.  users sometimes do the same.  if there's more than you want to retag manually feel free to post a new retag-request here to get the mods to run a batch retag.

Comment: @quack: Yeah, thanks. ATM, I don't have enough rep on either SF or SU to do retagging, so in those cases I don't have a choice but to post a request.